# Receiving a BAD REQUEST (400) response with Basecamp API 3 from a Node Express application

Tags: api, basecamp

The same request including the access token is working with **CURL** and **Postman**.

The code from Postman (masked credentials and ids) is included.

```
var http = require("https");
var options = {
  "method": "GET",
  "hostname": [
    "3",
    "basecampapi",
    "com"
  ],
  "path": [
    "<MASKED ACCOUNT ID>",
    "my",
    "profile.json"
  ],
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Bearer <MASKED AUTH TOKEN>",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "92fc7993-57aa-47f7-aaae-44925dd37f3e"
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
  });
});

req.end();
```

Comment: Switching from https to the request module fixed this problem.  I'd like to know why but so far it is very solid so moving ahead.  The quickest way to experiment is to generate code for Node using https (NodeJS Native) and another for Node using request (NodeJS Request) from Postman and try out an API request with each.

Answer (score 0):

Use NodeJS Request instead of NodeJS Native when creating code from a Postman request.